# MVC, PartialView has what looks like postback data?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm new to MVC and I'm trying to make my first Ajax page, PartialView.

What I have is an action that looks like this

```
[HttpGet]
public PartialViewResult MainContent()
{
    return PartialView(new ClockingModel());
}

[HttpPost]      
public PartialViewResult MainContent(SingleClocking SingleClocking)
{
   // update logic
   return PartialView(myClockingModel);
}
```

What I'm finding is that the view renders, I enter some data and it posts back correctly. My partial view includes a select:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SingleClocking.InWhen, new SelectList(Model.DropDownValues, Model.DefaultValue))
```

The select shows the value that I changed on the GUI, not the new DefaultValue?

If this was plain Asp.Net I would assume this was because of postback data or viewstate but MVC doesn't use either of these?

I can see the view being returned via fiddler, it shows the select with the value as per the client, not the value I expected to see via the server.

I'm sure I'm just missing something simple here, any hints?

Also, could I look at the value of the View on the server? This won't work but something like: string viewText = PartialView(myClockingModel);

p.s. I don't think it's caching, I tried switching that off with an attribute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And even though I searched for a while before asking this I finally found the answer.
I feel a bit better knowing that Rick Strahl had the same confusion.

Posting as an answer for others to find

Long story short, this is by design, the blog is worth reading

http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2012/Apr/20/ASPNET-MVC-Postbacks-and-HtmlHelper-Controls-ignoring-Model-Changes